# Root View controller is deallocated so how do I retain it or add it to my navigation controller again

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

After I logout using this:

```
- (IBAction) logoutButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [Users logOut];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The screen goes black if I have been logged in for like 12 hours.  I guess the rootview controller is deallocated.

This is how it's created in appDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    StartViewController *viewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
    StartNavigationController *navigationController=[[StartNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

How can I make startviewcontroller show again? Or whatever the root is?

Comment: The root view controller should never be deallocated, so something else must be going on. Where in the app delegate do you have that code? Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Updated above. And not using storyboads, doing things programmatically to learn the sdk better.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign self.window.rootViewController, a strong reference is created for that object and hence with ARC it would not be deallocated unless the object pointing to it was deallocated.
So your StartViewController is the rootViewController of a navigation controller. How do you add the controller where you call the poptoRootViewController?
When performing the pop, get the view controllers array of the navigation controller and make sure that your root view controller is intact.

Comment: How do I do that? And what if the root view controller is not intact?

Comment: Put a break point.
In the debugger, find self.navigationController.viewControllers.
This will give you an array of all the view controllers that are on the navigation stack.
If the root view controller is not present, that means it was cleared out of the memory, and when you pop to root view controller, there is nothing available for the navigation controller to show.